# XSLT Specify name space in parent node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, transformation, xml-namespaces, xslt

i am beginner into XSLT. I am using it to transform XML to XML.

**Source XML:**

```
<Response>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</Response>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://myexample.org/a"
xmlns:b="http://myexample.org/b"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Response" namespace="http://myexample.org/a">
        <xsl:element name="Root">
            <xsl:element name="a:Parent">
                <xsl:element name="b:Child">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<Root>
  <a:Parent xmlns:a="http://myexample.org/a">
    <b:Child xmlns:b="http://myexample.org/b">Hello</b:Child>
  </a:Parent>
</Root>
```

I would like to transform the XML into below XML using XSLT.

**Expected Outpout:**

```
<Root xmlns:a="http://myexample.org/a">
    <a:Parent xmlns:b="http://myexample.org/b">
        <b:Child/>
    </a:Parent>
<Root>
```

I have successfully created the XSLT to transform the data but here i am confused with namespaces. I am not able to generate it as above.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: First Read this [Why XSLT](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/whyxslt.html)

Comment: @vels4j: i know it is use to transform XML to XML. I am also doing the same but here the output XML should have mentioned structure. I have updated the question. Please let me know if that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit awkward to create namespace declarations at a specific place using XSLT 1.0 (it's much easier in 2.0 which has `<xsl:namespace>`) but it can be done with a trick to copy the namespace nodes from the *stylesheet* document itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://myexample.org/a"
xmlns:b="http://myexample.org/b"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <xsl:element name="Root">
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::a" />
            <xsl:element name="a:Parent">
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::b" />
                <xsl:element name="b:Child">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `document('')` parses the stylesheet document and gives you its root node, so `document('')/*` is the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.  We then extract from that element the *namespace node* bound to the specified prefix and copy that to the output document.

Alternatively, take out the namespace declarations from the `<xsl:stylesheet>` and use literal result elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <Root xmlns:a="http://myexample.org/a">
            <a:Parent xmlns:b="http://myexample.org/b">
                <b:Child>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
                </b:Child>
            </a:Parent>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

though this won't work if you need the `a` and `b` prefixes elsewhere in the stylesheet.